# “set -e” in a function

Tags: bash, shell, set, sh

How can I use `set -e` semantics in a function?

This is reopen to ["set -e" in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072984/set-e-in-a-function) question since it has not been answered correctly and has already been accepted.

Here is example:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -exo pipefail
f() {
    echo a
    false
    echo Should NOT get HERE
}
if f ; then
    true
fi
```

I would like `f` to exit at `false`.

My experiments show that using subshell `(f)` call doesn't help here:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -exo pipefail
f() {
    echo a
    false
    echo Should NOT get HERE
}
g() {   
    ( f )
}
if g ; then
    true
fi
```

Moving `f` out of the if statement does the job of course in this particular case:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -exo pipefail
f() {
    echo a
    false
    echo Should NOT get HERE
}
f
if [ "$?" != "0" ] ; then
    true
fi
```

This doesn't help me that much tough.

Is it possible to turn on `set -e` semantics when the function is executed from within the if predicate?

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate because asking a duplicate question isn't really a solution to being unhappy with an answer. It just fragments the answers, when we already have a mechanism to provide multiple answers. Can we clean this up back into a single question? I would be happy to unaccept and switch to the best answer again.