# why is bash -e disabled within a function run with not (!)

Tags: bash

**Note:** If you are **looking for a workaround** because set -e does not work in a function, please go to [“set -e” in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754845/set-e-in-a-function). This question is about **why** it does not work as expected.

When the following is run on GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release :

```
  set -ex

  PS4=' ${FUNCNAME[0]}: $LINENO: '

  function f() {
      set -e
      false
      echo $@
  }

  ! f why does it display ? It should stop because of -e
  f
```

It displays

```
 : 11: f why does it display '?' It should stop because of -e
 f: 6: set -e
 f: 7: false
 f: 8: echo why does it display '?' It should stop because of -e
why does it display ? It should stop because of -e
 : 12: f
 f: 6: set -e
 f: 7: false
```

I expect it to never go past the false, because `-e` means "exit when a command has a non zero exit status". I am aware that `-e` has a tricky behavior, as explained in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105 but I would like to understand what happens in this specific case. I am using `-e` and it proved most helpful in many very simple scenarios. This scenario is a little more tricky but if it can be explained I may use `-e` instead adding `|| exit 1` after each line.

Comment: From the 4.2 bash ref manual: "If the reserved word ‘!’ precedes the pipeline, the exit status is the logical negation of the exit status as described above."  So do you want "true" instead of "false"?

Comment: No, I don't want true. I want the echo $@ to never be run because of the -e and the preceding false.

Comment: Why do you mix comments and output? It just makes it unreadable.

Answer (score 6):

While trying to solve a similar problem, I read the [man page](http://ss64.com/bash/set.html) for `set -e`:

> `-e`   `errexit`
>
> Exit immediately if a simple command exits with a non-zero
>    status, unless the command that fails is part of an until or
>    while loop, part of an if statement, part of a `&&` or `||` list,
>    or if the command's return status is being inverted using `!`.

Note the last bit about the return status being inverted. I guess the logical negation of function `f` must have an effect on the behaviour of `set -e` within that function.

Answer (score 2):

Here's from the `trap` section of `man bash` (my emphasis):

> If a sigspec is ERR, the command arg is executed whenever a simple command has a non-zero exit status, subject to the following conditions. **The ERR trap is not executed if** the failed  command is  part  of  the  command list immediately following a while or until keyword, part of the test in an if statement,  part  of  a command  executed in a && or || list, or if **the command's return value is being inverted via !.  These are  the  same  conditions obeyed by the errexit option.**

So `! command` effectively disables the `ERR` `trap` inside `command`. I guess the reasoning is that you *might* not want a command exiting early if you are "kinda explicitly" checking the exit code after running it with `!`. Looks like bad design, since it can be used to effectively disable safeguards pretty much anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I can't precisely answer the *why*, but I found this snippet [here](http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/writing-robust-shell-scripts.html):

> On a slightly related note, by default bash takes the error status of the last item in a pipeline, which may not be what you want. For example, false | true will be considered to have succeeded. If you would like this to fail, then you can use set -o pipefail to make it fail.

And by updating your script as such:

```
function f() {
    echo $SHELLOPTS
    set -e
    set -o pipefail
    false
    echo "$@"
}
```

It seems to behave as you expect.

So my best guess for "why" (probably the same as yours by now), is that the `!` causes the function to be handled in some sort of "pipe" mode.  Again... why `!` means 'pipe', I guess I don't really know.  Maybe a better bash expert can answer that part for us.

Comment: This is a very nice workaround, thanks :-)

Comment: set -o pipefail does not work as you describe on my bash-4.1.5 . Which version of bash are you using ?

Comment: I'm using bash 4.1-3 from Debian 6.0.