# Bash: Force a subshell / block to stop on exit when the caller is calling the block as part of a logical fork

Tags: bash

I posted a question here: [Why is bash errexit not behaving as expected in function calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789102/why-is-bash-errexit-not-behaving-as-expected-in-function-calls)

The answer was because bash does not exit on error when the subshell, block or command list is part of a logical predicate for a `while`, `until`, `||`, `if`, `elif` or `&&` statement.

My next question is: How do you force the errexit option to be enforced in a subshell or block even if the caller is creating a logical fork.  For example, the command list that makes up a will stop on the first command that fails:

```
function a() { b ; c ; d ; e ; }
( set -e ; a )
```

But when you logically gate it, it doesn't:

```
( set -e ; a || false )
```

Calling `a` will execute `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` regardless of the return code.  Even if you make it explicit like so, bash ignores the errexit predicate:

```
function a() { ( set -e ; b ; c ; d ; e ) ; return $? ; }
( set -e ; a || false )
```

Comment: Short form: The behavior you're requesting is contrary to how errexit is defined, and thus unavailable.

Comment: ...see also: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Answer (score 0):

It would not make sense for bash to implement the requested behavior, because it would make decision trees useless -- you couldn't have a boolean operation return false and handle the case, because that return value would immediately cause an exit.

As such, bash *does not* implement that behavior. The general advice from #bash on freenode is to avoid set -e, and do your own error handling.

Comment: I disagree in the case of the subshell.  The subshell would exit and return the exit code of the command that failed.  This would be returned by the function and thus be used in the logical operation.  So it makes perfect sense.

Comment: Image a script `dostuff.sh` that intentionally leaves `-e` unset so that it works properly. Now imagine if `destuff.sh` were to inherit your script's setting of `-e`: it wouldn't work any more. That's why `-e` is not passed to subshells.

Comment: @chepner This is not about subshells. The problem is diagonal to what you wrote: the function explicitly sets an option `set -e` locally, but some rogue `||` N subshells above somehow overrides it. It's super dangerous. It defeats any hardening or security measures from the outside.

Comment: @charles-duffy The answer does not make sense. First, the question is not about the whole shell termination, just that the rest of the function should not be executed. The intuition is that `cmd1 || cmd2` is fully equivalent to `if ! cmd1; then cmd2; fi`. Sadly, with Bash this equivalence is violated. The `if` behavior doesn't impede decision trees in any way and neither would `||` were it implemented the same way. The `if` statement "eats" the errors, preventing them from causing the shell to exit. This is perfectly fine and this is how the `||` should behave.

Comment: @charles-duffy The current behavior of `||` actually **breaks** the decision trees. The following prints "false true", which is nonsense `function FalseFunc { set -e; false; echo false; }; if FalseFunc || false; then echo true; fi`

Comment: @Ark-kun, that "intuitive" behavior has never been true -- and it's not true in languages other than bash either. There's a reason Python -- a language intentionally sparing in its syntax -- implemented `if foo then bar else baz` as a one-liner syntax rather than encouraging use of the `foo && bar || baz` idiom; that idiom has the behavior you describe, and **always has**, in every language that ever implemented short-circuiting logic operators.

Comment: @charles-duffy I don't understand. Can you explain it in more detail? Please, explain your vision/definition of the `||` operator. I've always thought that `a || b` meant "a OR ELSE b" or more verbosely: "the expression evaluates to true if a evaluates to true/not-error or (otherwise) if b evaluates to true/not-error". But in Bash the meaning seems to be closer to "random OR ELSE b".

Comment: @charles-duffy Looks like my knowledge of Bash was flawed. I was certain that `if ! a; then ...` (unlike `a || ..`) does not cause the behavior I hate. I was certain I tested it under FreeBSD. But it seems that I'm wrong and `if ! a; then ...` behaves the same. To clarify: the behavior I hate is that failing function may evaluate to true value if placed alongside the `||` operator. Instead of the function short-circuiting to false, all statements are evaluated and the function may return true.

Comment: @Ark-kun, that's not an issue specific to bash -- *any* UNIX program exiting with a nonzero exit status doesn't give you a universal way to distinguish between nonzero-exit-status-conveying-false and nonzero-exit-status-conveying-error, except in the case of `WIFSIGNALED(status)`. There's a compelling argument to be made in favor of a more comprehensive convention, but unless you'd want to break the convention whereby external commands and internal shell commands behave similarly (not to mention compatibility with POSIX sh), it's a larger discussion than one about any single shell.

Comment: @charles-duffy >"that's not an issue specific to bash". For me, the issue *is* *sh specific as it only cripples shell functions, but not external scripts or executables. And thank god for that. Imagine what would happen if it affected the external programs too. Running `./prog` in a `./prog || { #handle problem; }` context would have essentially added the dreaded the error `ON ERROR RESUME NEXT` (or `try { line } catch {}` around every code line) to the unsuspecting `./prog`.

Comment: @charles-duffy >"that's not an issue specific to bash -- any UNIX program exiting with a nonzero exit status doesn't give you a universal way to distinguish between nonzero-exit-status-conveying-false and nonzero-exit-status-conveying-error". Bash devs have chosen the "nonzero exit status means crash (with errexit) or false (in conditionals)" notation for their shell language constructs. The problem lies not in the behavior, but in the externally changeable behavior of a seemingly encapsulated shell function that the function cannot defend against.

Comment: @charles-duffy On the other hand, Bash also allows crippling any code with `alias echo="rm -rf ~/ "`. The only difference is that one way of crippling is implicit and surprising, while the other is an explicit foot-shooting.

Comment: Fair 'nuff. As I've said before (and, for that matter, allude in this answer), `set -e` is a hack, and using or relying on it potentially unwise. If your examples aren't found in BashFAQ #105, by the way, you might consider adding them.

Comment: (That said -- no, that alias _won't_ cripple code in scripts, as aliases don't work in scripts at all unless explicitly enabled; see the `expand_aliases` shopt option).